# Running several functions in PS Script, and exporting all to 1 CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write something simple to audit a workstation configuration, in the even I need to replace a client computer, or re-image it. To record what all was configured on it before. The script I've made so far is

```
$Output="C:\CompConfig.csv"
$Printers=Get-Printer | Select-Object Name,Type,PortName,Shared
$Drives=Get-PSDrive | where{$_.DisplayRoot -match "\\"}
$Accounts=Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property      NumberOfLicensedUsers,NumberOfUsers,RegisteredUser
$Software=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion    \Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate

$CompConfig=???????

$CompConfig | Export-Csv -Path $Output
```

However I cannot figure out what the $CompConfig function should look like.

Comment: Sorry, first time here. My idea would be to format the CSV in such a way it appears you exported each one of these functions individually, and then copy and pasted them into one CSV. I had originally wrote this using Out-File and Appending each function to the Out-File, but it wrote the entire line into one cell and not multiple. And it was really hard to read through.

Comment: I also wouldn't mind if it exported all of it to XML or HTML, I mostly just want a file, with all the data in it, that isn't a nightmare to read.

Comment: someone removed my comment asking you to add an example of how you want the data to be structured in the output file. [*sigh ...*] ///// so, have you tried exporting each collection to a CSV and then inserting each of those CSV files into a plain text file? or into an HTML file using `ConvertTo-Html` & it's various parameters?

Comment: I have tried configuring them all into their own separate csv file, but I have not had any luck in getting the 4 individual files, back into one file. This is where my  brain is getting stuck. I'm still new to PS, and have been Googling all day.

Comment: run this `$Printers | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\PrinterInfo.html"` and then load the resulting file in a browser. that seems quite readable. ///// if all you want is the raw text of all the CSV files, export each $Var to a CSV and then simply insert each into a text file with a few lines between each block of info.

Answer (score 0):

> I also wouldn't mind if it exported all of it to XML or HTML, I mostly just want a file, with all the data in it, that isn't a nightmare to read.

Since the format isn't all that important, as long as it's readable, here's a proposed solution, using JSON:

```
$Output="C:\CompConfig.json"
$Printers=Get-Printer | Select-Object Name,Type,PortName,Shared
$Drives=Get-PSDrive | where{$_.DisplayRoot -match "\\"}
$Accounts=Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property NumberOfLicensedUsers,NumberOfUsers,RegisteredUser
$Software=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate

$CompConfig = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Printers = $Printers
    Drives = $Drives
    Accounts = $Accounts
    Software = $Software
}

$CompConfig |
    ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File $Output
```